# I'm trying to reinstall ubuntu but I cannot find the option?

Tags: reinstall

These are the options that I have available:

[image]

And this is what I've got if I try "Something Else":

[image]

What can I do to reinstall it without losing my files?

UPDATE: Is this how I should select the options?
[image]

Comment: **You should have backups anyway**, anything that can potentially change partitions has a data loss risk. That said, in this case, assuming you want to reinstall the same version, you can select all the partitions of the previous - `/` (sda2), `swap` (sda3) - and the ESP (EFI System Partition) (sda1) but do NOT format. This keeps everything in `/home` but not previously user installed software (software configurations are preserved at `/home` but the software must be reinstalled). Probably better to save your files somewhere else and do a fresh install.

Comment: MichaelBay's suggestion should work, but note that anything you changed that is a system file or setting, will be overwritten and defaults will be used. Only the files you created will not be erased and only if you DO NOT check the format option on / or if you had /home as a separate partition.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did a backup yesterday just in case.  So do I click on "Something else" then? And then I select /dev/sda? (the very first option of the list). I do have windows installed in another partition. I'm sorry for my silly question I'm a bit lost here.just

Comment: 1. Always follow @oldfred 's recommendations. 2. "Install alongside will create two distinct installation and I suppose you don't want that. You can use the method I explained before, with "something else" but instead select format in the root partition (`/`). This will reuse the partitions but the installed system will be as new.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got it. The device for boot loader installation should be /dev/sda as well I suppose? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yes, choose sda for that.

Comment: "no root file system is defined". I guess I need to create another partition.

Comment: Guys, shouldn't boot loader install device be /dev/sda*1* where the efi partition is?

Comment: @Rosamunda, you do not need to create a new partition. Looking at your screen shot, I think `/dev/sda2` was your original root file system. So you should select `/` as the mount point for this partition, and /dev/sda2 will be defied as your root partition for the new install. Be sure to NOT format this, as  MichaelBay has suggested.

Comment: You always install the boot loader (grub) to a drive. With UEFI, Ubuntu's version of grub only actually installs to the ESP - efi system partition on drive seen as sda, or first drive if NVMe. But that is unique to Ubuntu's grub as a Fedora install did install to the ESP on sdb when drive sdb selected during install.

Comment: Take a look at
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes for a better way to use your 4T disk space.